# Object Id set as null when saving - AjaxDependencySelection

Tags: grails

So I decided to use AjaxDependencySelection Plugin for Grails, and it has proven to be very useful. However, I am trying to implement autoComplete boxes, and it does not seem to be saving the object id when using an Autocompleted selection. Here is my implementation in my gsp

```
<g:selectPrimary id="template" name="template"
domain='dms.nexusglobal.Template'
searchField='templateName'
collectField='id'

domain2='dms.nexusglobal.Tag'
bindid="template.id"
searchField2='tagName'
collectField2='id'

hidden="hiddenNew"
noSelection="['': 'Please choose Template']" 
setId="tag"
value="${documentPartInstance?.template}"/>

<g:selectSecondary id="tag" name="tag"
domain2='dms.nexusglobal.Subtag'
bindid="tag.id"
searchField2='subtagName'
collectField2='id'

autocomp="1"

noSelection="['': 'Please choose Tag']" 
setId="subtag"
value="${documentPartInstance?.tag}"/>


<g:autoCompleteSecondary id="subtag" name="subtagId"

domain='dms.nexusglobal.Subtag'
primarybind='tag.id'
hidden='tag'
hidden2='hidden5'
searchField='subtagName'
collectField='id'

value='${documentPartInstance?.subtag}'/>

 <input type=hidden id="hidden5" name="subtagId" value="${documentPartInstance?.subtag}"/>
```

However, everytime I save it, I am presented with this error `Column 'subtag_id' cannot be null` . Here is my domain class definition for Subtag

```
class Subtag {
static scaffold = true

String subtagName
static belongsTo = [tag : Tag]

public Subtag()
{

}

public Subtag(String s)
{
    subtagName = s
}

static constraints = {
}

String toString(){
    subtagName
}
}
```

Tag hasMany subtags as well

It seems to be creating new Subtag instances when using the autoselect box (as an error shows up saying `Could not find matching constructor for:packagename.Subtag(java.lang.String)` Although this is a feature I am looking to implement in my application at later stages (being able to create new Subtags on the fly when creating a document Part), right now, all I would like to be able to do is just choose from my already existing subtags.

When I add in a string constructor, it comes back with the error that `Column subtag_id cannot be null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed it so will try help you through your issue.

The problem is that you are trying to push a value from selectSecondary and update the elementId of g:autocomplete which is actually a seperate entity.

I will update the plugin with a new method, need to test it out first.. Also take a look at g:selectAutoComplete. Although this method would only work if your secondary was the primary task... so no good in that case either..

hang on and look out for 0.37 release

Released 0.37 documentation on how to do such a thing here: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselection/wiki/from-selection-to-autocomplete---how-to

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, something seems to be wrong with my implementation. I have update my original post to now show my _form gsp with 0.37.

Comment: I have just tested 0.37 directly from the plugin and the selectauto3 example is working with the plugin... you need to provide further information with what is going wrong.. Try opening Tools Developer / Web console and when you fill in the form - when you get to third element this being auto complete - what happens below in the console - do you see an error - what does the error show ? if it is 200 on a url - copy url test it out - send link if fails or passes

Comment: I have also made example domain classes and test page with your identical code above which works - perhaps its your domain relationship that is the cause of the issue. take a look at the example site domainclasses and https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselectexample/blob/master/grails-app/views/myContinent/selectauto2.gsp which I just tested and showed me values in auto complete...

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my database/database config, I switched my datasource.groovy to the default and everything worked fine. Thanks for all your help. Now to dig into my mysql database and see what the problem is.

Comment: backup db do a mysqldump -d {dbname} -u {user} -p > /tmp/db1.txt then remove db - let it generate from scratch repeat above dump command - compare the two structures - restore original - fix issue on orig